# Configure (no) retries for Spark job in Livy submit

Tags: apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform, azure-hdinsight

When submitting a long-running Spark batch job through Livy, the job is defaulting to five retries, which takes forever to finally fail. How can I change this so the job fails immediately?

My environment is Spark 1.6, running on Azure HDInsight (HDP).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a configuration on your yarn, not on Livy.
Go to yarn's configuration page under "Advanced yarn-site" and change "yarn.resourcemanager.am.max-attempts" from 5 to 1 if you want it to do no retry.

Comment: Found it. Thanks!